# Getting "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error" when running my PHP app

Tags: php, mysql

Good day!

I am working on building a dummy application form that inserts data to a mySQL database. When running the functions, I successfully insert the data into the database. However, when the functions worked successfully, I am getting an error *SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error*

I thought it was occurring within my database access function, but it seems to be connecting alright. Here is my db access function:

```
    function connectToDB($params)
    {

    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($params['sql']);
        $stmt->execute($params['bindParam']);
        $results = array();
        $results['rowCount'] = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($results['rowCount'] == 1)
        {

            $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $results;

        } elseif($results['rowCount'] < 2) {

            $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $results; 

        } elseif($results['rowCount'] > 2) {

            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $results;

        } elseif($results['rowCount'] == 2) {

            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $results;

        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

    }

    return $params;

}
```

Is there something I am missing in my code or is there something that shouldn't be in my db access code? I hope to learn from this to apply it in the future while I'm still trying to learn/improve on my PHP along the way. I hope I did my best to explain my issue and I appreciate your time reading!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use `fetchAll()`.

`$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

with insert queries. Removing this statement it should fix your problem. Remember every fetch and fetchAll from your code.

Comment: Using a fetch while I am doing a foreach loop messes up my c'R'ud data.

Comment: Using a fetch while I am doing a foreach loop messes up my c'R'ud data.

*edit: I decided to remove the fetches from my db access function and put them in the functions that run sql SELECT and it worked perfectly! Thank you for this